# Pandas - chaining multiple .loc methods.

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, is there a way to combine both indexing by label and indexing by boolean mask in a single .loc call?

Currently I have this:

`df.loc[start_date:end_date][[np.is_busday(x, holidays=dd.all_holidays) for x in df.index]]`

Which works fine but I am curious if there is a better alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @YOLO, Would you consider deleting your comment (as it doesn't work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the index to a series and then use `pd.Series.between` and `pd.Series.apply`:

```
s = pd.Series(df.index)

df.loc[s.between(start_date, end_date) & \
       s.apply(np.is_busday, holidays=dd.all_holidays)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query may be more efficient as it will be vectorized, but it all depends on how much data you filtered out in the first place.

```
df.query(
    '(@start_date <= index < @end_date) & '
    '@np.is_busday(index, holidays=@dd.all_holidays)'
)
```

Side note, are your certain that your boolean mask works? df and the dataframe (returned by loc) that you are indexing with the mask might not have the same length anymore.

Comment: `np.is_busday` can be be vectorized by calling `np.is_busday(df.index.values.astype('M8[D]')` - `np.is_busday(df.index)` does not work. I am unsure if your query syntax is correct.

Comment: Also - good catch on the the boolean mask - I was testing a case where `start_date` and `end_date` were both equal to `None`